# My javafx graphics doesn't show the images on the buttons I have created

Tags: javafx-8

```
package javafxskel;

import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import static javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
```

Maybe something wrong with my imports. I have also tried to paste filepath in `new Image("")`

```
public class JavaFXSkel extends Application {

    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Inside the innit method()");
    }

    public void start(Stage myStage) {

        myStage.setTitle("WINDOW");

        FlowPane rootNode = new FlowPane(10, 10);
        rootNode.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(rootNode, 250, 250);
        myStage.setScene(myScene);
```

I dont' know if there is some more details that you have to know but this the code

```
    Image picture = new Image("file:pictureIcon.jpeg");
    Image save = new Image("file:saveIcon.jpeg");

    Label response = new Label("push a button");

    Button btnpicture = new Button("Picture", new ImageView(picture));
    Button btnsave = new Button("Save", new ImageView(save));

    btnpicture.setContentDisplay(GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    btnsave.setContentDisplay(GRAPHIC_ONLY);

    btnpicture.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
            response.setText("Picture button");
        }

    });
    btnsave.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
            response.setText("Save button");
        }

    });

    rootNode.getChildren().add(btnpicture);
    rootNode.getChildren().add(btnsave);
    rootNode.getChildren().add(response);

    myStage.show();

}
```

Comment: The `file:pictureIcon.jpeg` URL will locate the file relative to the _working directory_ of the application. If your image is a _resource_ then you should be using a scheme-less URL where the path is the package path to the resource (i.e. the same path you'd use as the argument to [`ClassLoader#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String))). If your image is at the root of the classpath then using `new Image("pictureIcon.jpeg")` should work.

Comment: If the above doesn't help you then please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Doing `System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());` would provide valuable info, but you'd still need to show the location you store the images in your file system (That is if you indeed want to load an image file instead of a resource from your classpath/jar).

Comment: @fabian  I have my images at package javafx skel. I also have them on my desktop. I am using mac too if does any difference.